# Getting data from DB2 for highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I am new to highcharts. I am currently using DB2. May I know how can I get data using the followings:

1) select statement
2) stored procedure
3) user defined function

I am not too sure if I did it correctly. I have this code in the xhtml h:head section

```
<?php
    $sql = "select ccy, vdate, valrate from belsize.excrate where enterpriseid = '9cd15270-013d-f4d3-f70c-c0a80172aa77' and vdate >= '2013-10-01' and vdate <= '2013-10-10' and ccy = 'MYR'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $excrate = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $excrate[] = $row['ccy'];
        $excrate[] = $row['vdate'];
        $excrate[] = $row['valrate'];
    }
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#container2').highcharts({
            title: {
                text: 'Exchange Rate',
                x: -20 //center
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: From Excrate table',
                x: -20
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Rate'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ''
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'middle',
                borderWidth: 0
            },
            series: [{
        data: [<?php echo join($excrate, ', '); ?>]

        }]
        });
    });
</script>
```

Under h:form section I have the below codes

```
<div id="container2" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: Man.. google something, try something before posting your doubts here.. And sure we would be very happy to contribute.. :)

Comment: How your data looks like when you print here:    echo join($excrate, ', ');

Answer (score 0):

Highcharts is javascript library, which get data as CSV / XML / JSON or other file which can be parsed by javascript. So all depends on your choice, how data will be retrun from database. Highcharts has no handlers to database.

Please familair with this article: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/preprocessing